# Differentiate between 1D and 2D container in template class constructor (SFINAE)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

So, I have a class, which has an array of arrays as a private member. I wish to have two constructors for each case (1D or 2D). But of course their declaration happens to be the same, so template deduction can't do its job without me doing something about it. Here's the code:

**Edit:** I also need it to work with STL containers like vector or C++ array. That is why I am overcomplicating and not going with the "arrays" fix.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<class T, std::size_t rows_t, std::size_t cols_t>
class test
{
private:
    std::array<std::array<T, cols_t>, rows_t> _data;
public:    
    auto begin() { return this->_data.begin(); }
    auto end() { return this->_data.end(); }


    //CONSTRUCTOR
    template<class type_t>
    test(const type_t &arr)
    {
        std::size_t j = 0;
        for (const auto &num : arr)
            this->_data[0][j++] = num;
    }

    template<class type_t>
    test(const type_t &arr)
    {
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for (const auto &el : arr)
        {
            std::size_t j = 0;
            for (const auto &num : el)
                this->_data[i][j++] = num;
            ++i;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    double arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    double arr2[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };

    test<double, 1, 3> obj = arr; 
    test<double, 2, 2> obj2 = arr2;

    for (const auto &i : obj2)
    {
        for (const auto &j : i)
            std::cout << j << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

**Note:** I've been reading about `enable_if`, but I don't quite understand how it works. Can it be done with that?

Comment: Why would you need two cases when you *know* `_data` is 2 dimensional?

Comment: For convenience. Sometimes _data might have 1 row and 3 columns, making it one-dimensional.

Comment: You could use 1D array as backing data structure for arrays of any dimensionality and calculate indices instead (at least if they are dense). This will eliminate the problem. But frankly, you already have 1D array (`std::array`) and 2D array should be a separate data type (class).

Comment: `auto begin() { return this->_data.begin(); }` This is going to return an iterator for the outer dimension. You sure this is what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I'm quite sure. That's how I am able to do the ranged-for loop at the end of the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to "teach" the compiler what's 2D and what's not. Hence, you have to define something like the following type trait:

```
template<typename T>
struct is2D : public std::false_type {};
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
struct is2D<std::array<std::array<T, M>, N>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T>
struct is2D<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
struct is2D<T[N][M]> : std::true_type {};
```

Then you could set up your class definition in the following way:

```
template<class T, std::size_t rows_t, std::size_t cols_t>
class test{
  std::array<std::array<T, cols_t>, rows_t> _data;

  template<class type_t>
  std::enable_if_t<!is2D<type_t>::value, void>
  test_init(type_t const &arr) {
    std::size_t j = 0;
    for (const auto &num : arr) _data[0][j++] = num;
  }

  template<class type_t>
  std::enable_if_t<is2D<type_t>::value, void>
  test_init(type_t const &arr) {
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for(const auto &el : arr) {
      std::size_t j = 0;
      for (const auto &num : el) _data[i][j++] = num;
      ++i;
    }
  }

public:

  auto &operator[](const std::size_t &i) { return this->_data[i]; }
  auto begin() { return this->_data.begin(); }
  auto end() { return this->_data.end(); }

  //CONSTRUCTOR
  template<class type_t> test(type_t const &arr) { test_init(arr); }
};
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7e5bc3bc8891509)

Comment: Sorry, I already had done that. I should have specified. It doesn't satisfy me though, because it would only work on C arrays and not on let's say a vector or C++ array. :)

Answer (score 2):

The constructors should not be the same, but you have only provided the most generic matching possible.

SFINAE is not necessary here. Just provide a constructor for a 1D array, and a separate constructor for a 2D array:

```
template <typename T2, std::size_t N>
test( const T2 (&a)[N] )
{
  ...
}

template <typename T2, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
test( const T2 (&a)[M][N] )
{
  ...
}
```

Another note: POSIX reserves typenames ending with "_t", so it is typically a good idea to avoid them in your own code. (Obnoxious, I know.) Standard C++ will use Camel Case of the form: `RowsType`, etc, and then **typedef** a `rows_type` for users of the class.

Notice, however, that `rows_t` is not actually a type -- it is a *value.* A better name would be something like `NRows`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please give some examples of standard C++ using CamelCase instead of snake_case.

Comment: Seriously? `T`, `CharT`, `Traits`, `ForwardIterator`, etc. Pick one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude.